# How to move each character in a TextArea with ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to go through a textarea to find and separate certain strings, such as:

> Example 1) Separate the numbers from the text.

String "KAEeqk41KK      EeqkKEKQ3 EKEK 43"  -  Result: [41, 3, 43]

> Example 2) Count the blanks in the String.

OBS: **_ = blank space
 String "KAkeaekaek _** kea41 __ 3k1k31"

Comment: `string.match(/\d+/g)` to extract the numbers.

Comment: In your *count the blanks* requirement, what is the result you expect for your sample string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *separate the numbers* using `match()` and count some match using length, I'm not sure what do you mean with blanks but this example could be useful.

```js
//var str = document.getElementById("textarea").value;//<-- probably somethig like this

var str = "KAEeqk41KK EeqkKEKQ3 EKEK 43";

var str2 = "KAkeaekaek _ kea41 __ 3k1k31"

var numbers = str.match(/[0-9]+/g)

var blanks = str2.match(/_| /g).length//<-- count spaces and _

console.log(numbers)
console.log(blanks)
```